# Sens de « jamais » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: sens, adverbes

> « Est-ce que M. Letondu est parti ? » il eut, de la tête, un léger recul étonné :
> – M’sieu Letondu ? Ah ben oui… Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures.
> – Du soir ? s’exclama M. de La Hourmerie.
> – Bien sûr, du soir.
> Le garçon de bureau ricana, amusé de la figure du chef qu’abrutissait
> cette révélation. Et il conta la belle histoire arrivée à Boudin, le concierge, quelques jours auparavant.   Celui-ci, las d’avoir attendu
> vainement jusqu’à plus de neuf heures et demie le départ de Letondu,
> inquiet, naturellement, et pressé de se mettre au lit, avait fini par monter voir en personne, une bougie au fond d’un cornet de papier. Doucement il avait entrebâillé la porte et passé le haut de la tête en déclarant d’une voix à la fois suave et ferme :
> – Faut s’en aller, monsieur Letondu ;
> les bureaux ferment à quatre heures.

Il est apparent que la phrase contenant « jamais » signifie « Je m’étonne s’il ne s’en va pas avant dix heures ».

Quel est le sens de « jamais » dans ce texte ? (donner une définition de dictionnaire, TLFi, sinon un autre)

Il y a l'interprétation suivante.

- Je m'étonne s'il ne lui arrive pas de s'en aller avant dix heures

C'est une interprétation qui est très présente à l'esprit et qui brouille la compréhension. Est-ce que le sens apparent pourrait de nos jours être rendu selon la construction de Courteline de façon tout aussi valide ? (Ça ne me semble pas vrai.)

Comment: Oui, effectivement, ouvrir un dictionnaire et trouver _jamais_ dedans serait suffisant ici.

Comment: Vous êtes si sûr de ça ? Vous vous imaginez que je n'ai pas ouvert un dictionnaire ?

Comment: Ben --- je sais pas, je suis certainement très bête, mais j'ai l'impression que c'est le **1er** sens que donne TLFi... Du style, 1.A. Carrèment. Mais bon, j'dis ça, j'dis rien.

Comment: @Frank Tout à fait, j'écrivais quand ton commentaire est arrivé. Sens positif de jamais, sans corrélation avec une particule négative. Ici ça veut dire « un jour quelconque ».

Comment: @Frank Vous ne savez pas alors… On attendra les réponses d'autres utilisateurs.

Comment: LPH kiffe _que dalle_ (je _souligne_). Incroyable.

Comment: Et ya pas que le TLF https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23093/la-grammaire/ladverbe/ladverbe-jamais, ça doit aussi être dans grevisse et autres.

Comment: @Frank Je ne parle ni arabe ni argot.

Comment: Ah pardon, c'est carrèment _du français_ maintenant (je tiens à souligner).

Comment: Oui, c'est dans Grevisse. On n'a pas [la même édition](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17649/lph) la mienne est bien plus ancienne mais je serais étonné que ça ait été enlevé, c'est toujours d'actualité. Adverbes de temps, jamais, c'est au début du §.

Comment: @Frank Chacun son français, que ce soit le votre.

Comment: @LPH Ah bon? Je croyais qu'il n'y avait qu'un (je souligne) _seul_ français correct, celui de la France française? Mais bon, le tiens c'est Fantasy French, ça, y'a pas de doute. Tu peux aussi me mettre le circonflexe à vôtre stp? Tu fais pas mal de fôtes d'ortograf en fait...

Comment: @None « je m’étonne s’il s’en va [à un moment quelconque] avant dix heures», selon le TLFi (user Franck), « je m’étonne s’il s’en va [à aucun moment] avant dix heures» (vitrine) : c'est contradictoire.

Comment: *Aucun* a aussi un sens positif. Voir TLF, Grevissse : « Aucun a étymologiquement la valeur positive de « quelque, quelqu'un » [voir historique]... cette valeur il l'a conservée dans des phrases interrogatives ou dubitatives, ou ... » . « je m’étonne s’il s’en va [à aucun moment] avant dix heures », c'est dubitatif. Rien de contradictoire entre les deux pour moi (ou alors il faut m'expliquer).

Comment: @None Il me semble que l'on ne choisirait pas ce sens pour le moins inhabituel dans le but de définir un mot.

Comment: @LPH J'ai trop le seum. TLFi te le met en tête de liste, avec plein d'exemples, et tu dis que c'est un sens _pour le moins inhabituel_?

Comment: Mais il se trouve que dans ce cas précis c'est de sens qu'il s'agit. Et c'est inhabituel pour toi, pour moi  je suppose pas que moi. Personne en connait tous les mots et tous les sens des mots, on apprend tous les jours....

Comment: @None Ce n'est pas la seule contradiction ;  « je m’étonne s’il s’en va [à un moment quelconque] avant dix heures» signifie qu'il part toujours après dix heures, mais ce n'est pas ce que le texte laisse entendre : il part toujours avant.

Comment: @LPH Je me demande si *ever* n'est pas un équivalent exact dans ce cas : quelque chose comme *I find myself  surprised if he ever leaves before ten*.

Comment: @guillaume31 Votre phrase signifie qu'il ne s'en va pratiquement jamais avant dix heures, mais le sens dans le texte de Courteline est tout le contraire : il s'en va pratiquement toujours avant  dix heures. « Ah ben oui » signifie que Letondu est bien parti, et en explication , Ovide (celui qui répond) dit qu'il serait étonnant que Letondu soit encore là parce que l'heure (à peu près dix heures) est une heure où il est déjà parti (d'habitude). — C'est l'interprétation qui me semble correcte, mais je comprends très mal le contexte dans lequel se situe cette partie.

Comment: @LPH Je pense que c'est l'inverse. Voir la réponse de None. Je ne connais pas suffisamment le roman pour dire d'où Letondu est "parti" et pourquoi ce "parti" équivaut à "ne pas s'en aller" mais il doit y avoir une explication. Ou alors Ovide est ironique quand il dit "Ah ben oui".

Comment: @guillaume31 Dans ce cas « Ah ben oui » ne signifierait pas « oui, il est parti ». Mais ce qui est bizarre, c'est qu'attendre le départ de Letondu jusqu'à plus de neuf heures et demi semble inhabituel ; le concierge doit lui rappeler que l'heure de partir est passée. (J'ai ajouté le texte relatif à ce récit dans la question.)

Comment: Ce n'est pas inhabituel pour lui de rester jusqu'à une heure tardive de la nuit, c'est justement ce que l'anecdote d'Ovide cherche à montrer avec malice. Si son habitude était de partir à l'heure ou avant, jamais il ne serait question de "dix heures". On dirait plutôt : *Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant [4/5/6] heures* maximum.

Comment: @guillaume31 Ça semble se tenir ; je crois comprendre maintenant : « Ah ben oui » ne serait pas la réponse directe à la question, c'est à dire ça ne signifierait pas « oui, il est parti…».

Comment: @LPH ça, ou la configuration des lieux fait que Letondu peut sembler être à la fois parti de l'endroit où se trouvent La Hourmerie et Ovide mais en réalité resté au travail...

Comment: @LPH None t'avait donné la réponse le 13 juillet déjà.

Comment: @Frank Oui, mais sans clarifier « Ah ben oui… », qui induit en erreur, et qu'il ne faut pas oublier.

Comment: @LPH le "Ah ben oui" n'a absolument rien à voir là-dedans. Même si le texte ne contenait pas ce "ah ben oui", le sens serait très clair.

Comment: @Frank Pour le coup, je suis plutôt d'accord avec LPH. « Ah ben oui… » induit bien en erreur (voilà aussi pourquoi je ne comprends toujours pas les downvotes...) C'est notre sens de la langue de natif qui nous fait négliger ce détail contradictoire pour se concentrer sur la partie de la phrase qui nous parait la plus signifiante.

Comment: @guillaume31 Je ne vois pas ce _ah ben oui_ comme contradictoire, et de toute façon, le fond du débat est sur l'expression _Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures_, qui se comprend de la même et unique façon, que _ah ben oui_ soit présent ou pas. Ce _ah ben oui_ est orthogonal.

Comment: @Frank Je ne suis pas d'accord. « Ah ben oui… » répond, en toute logique et en première impression d'un individu du XXIème iècle, à la question « Est-ce que M. Letondu est parti ? » qui est le centre même du débat.

Comment: @guillaume31 Le titre de la question contient _jamais_ est l'OP discute spécifiquement l'expression _s’il s’en va **jamais** avant dix heures_, à l'exclusion du _ah ben oui_. Et encore une fois, _ah ben oui_ ne module en aucun cas le sens de _s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures_. Si ce _ah ben oui_ n'était pas là, dirais-tu que le sens de _s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures_ serait différent?

Comment: @Frank Il serait sans équivoque. Tandis que si « Ah ben oui… » est là, il existe une hésitation. Il suffit d'introduire la réponse « oui, il est parti » pour révéler encore davantage la contradiction : comment peut-il être parti s'il ne part jamais avant 10h ? Bien sûr, il faut s'entourer de toutes les précautions concernant ce "parti" : d'où ? Vers où ? Mais au vu du contexte, je penche de plus en plus pour un « Ah ben oui... » ironique.

Comment: @guillaume31 Je ne ressens pas d'hésitation, d'équivoque ou de "contradiction". Et encore une fois, ni _oui il est parti_, ni _ah ben oui_ ne peuvent changer le sens de _Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures._ Je peux imaginer un ton sur lequel _ah ben oui_ va très bien avec la suite. Le garçon de bureau constate avec surprise ("_étonné_") que Letondu est déjà parti, et il enchaîne pour justififer sa surprise en commentant: _Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures._

Comment: @Frank L'auteur ne donne aucune indication que ce « Ah ben oui... » puisse être le résultat d'une constatation visuelle d'Ovide. D'ailleurs les deux hommes sont dans le bureau de La Hourmerie, pas de Letondu. De plus, dans la suite du texte (cf lien donné par @None), Letondu n'est pas parti mais bien dans son cabinet. Les deux phrases sont bel et bien en contradiction avec tout le contexte, si ce n'est entre elles.

Comment: @guillaume31 Pas pour moi, je ne vois pas la "contradiction".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pour compléter la réponse de @None :

La clé pour comprendre le passage, c'est que « Ah ben oui… » est fort probablement une formule ironique, assimilable à « Ben voyons ! » - voir https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/64693

Une fois cet écueil résolu, tous les éléments font sens avec l'affirmation suivante d'Ovide prise isolément, à savoir que Letondu ne quitte jamais le bureau *avant* dix heures.

Comment: Cette référence confirme admirablement un  pressenti difficile à propos d'une ambigüité assez subtile.

Comment: Ca marche avec l'interprétation "ben voyons!", mais tout ce que cela fait est de rendre le protagoniste encore plus incrédule incrédule, ce qui est souligné par la phrase suivante _Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures_. Ce protagoniste ne s'attend pas à ce que Letondu soit déjà parti - mais sans le _ah ben oui_, le sens de la phrase suivante aurait été exactement le même, et la situation d'étonnement du protagoniste exactement la même.

Comment: Je dirais plutôt que vu le sens (unique) de _Je m’étonne s’il s’en va jamais avant dix heures_ (Letondu ne part _jamais_ avant dix heures), l'expression _Ah ben oui!_ devient plus facile à interpréter comme _Ben voyons!_. Ovide n'y croit pas _donc_ ce _Ah ben oui!" est ironique.

Answer (score 4):

*Le bon usage* :

> *Aucun* a étymologiquement la valeur positive de « quelque, quelqu'un » ... cette valeur il l'a conservée dans des phrases interrogatives ou dubitatives, ...

Même chose [dans  la BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23093/la-grammaire/ladverbe/ladverbe-jamais) :

> Lorsque *jamais* est utilisé dans un sens négatif avec *ne* ou *sans*, il signifie « en aucun temps », « à aucun moment ».

C'est le sens 1 donné dans le TLF :

> I. − [Jamais n'est pas en corrélation avec une particule négative] À un moment quelconque, à quelque moment que ce soit.

La phrase introduite par « je m'étonne » peut être reformulée ainsi : « je serais étonné si à aucun moment (quelque soir) il s'en va avant dix heures ».

[La suite de la conversation](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Messieurs_les_ronds-de-cuir/Texte_entier) entre les deux hommes confirme d'ailleurs que la phrase ne peut que vouloir dire : « il ne part jamais avant dix heures ». Ovide, le garçon de bureau, relate que Boudin, le concierge, qui, un soir à neuf heures et demie, était allé voir si M. de La Hourmerie était prêt à partir, l'avait trouvé dans une position étrange et était reparti sans rien dire ; depuis Boudin se couchait  à huit heures moins le quart et laissait  M. de La Hourmerie sortir quand celui-ci le lui demandait au milieu de la nuit.

Comment: Oui, en appui: la compréhension normale et immédiate de cette phrase est bien qu'il ne part _jamais_ (ou très rarement) avant dix heures.